# How to host ASP.NET C# page using Word object in a server which do not have MS Office?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to create an instance of a COM class, it throws this exception:

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

I have used MS Word 15.0 object library. It works well on localhost. But when I try host it in a Windows web server, I get this error. I think the Windows server doesn't have MS Office.

Please suggest how could I solve it?

Comment: Word will need to be installed on the web server or you'll need to use a 3rd party library to manipulate Word documents.

Comment: Will publishing the site will help

Comment: can you suggest any 3rd party library

Comment: You could start here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=word&target=VS&category=Controls&vsVersion=&subCategory=All&sortBy=Relevance

Comment: Note that you're likely not licensed to run MS Office on the server. Make sure you [read MS's guidance](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) on this matter. Using another library is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks Daniel it works fine with GemBox